# WCF Service wsHttpBinding

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I'm getting error while creating wcf service using wsHtpBinding help page is getting error and services also not working

**Help Page Error**:

> The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
>   http://localhost:80/Service1.svc/help

My old working wsHttpbinding project web.config but it's not working now:

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="10000000"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding >
        <binding name="MyBasicwsHttpBinding">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors"  name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="mex"  binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBasicwsHttpBinding" name="WcfService1.Service1" contract="WcfService1.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found out that a Microsoft IIS filtering module [Url Scan 3.1](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/urlscan) was installed on IIS/website, which have it's own limit to reject incoming requests based on content size and return "404 Not found page".

It's limit can be updated in `%windir%\System32\inetsrv\urlscan\UrlScan.ini` file by setting `MaxAllowedContentLength` to the required value.

For eg. following will allow upto 300 mb requests

MaxAllowedContentLength=314572800